# Parameterized Cron Expression using appsetting.json C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, cron

I am trying to create a Time Trigger Attribute using a Cron Expression in my Azure Function. I want to see the Cron Expression from the appsetting.json.
I have referenced code here but with no luck https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-expressions

Here is my code":

Here is my where I am trying to pass the the cron expression as a variable but TimerTriggerDaily has an error message that says the parameter doesn't exist in the current context   (I have referenced using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;)

```
 [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
 public async Task Run([TimerTrigger(TimerTriggerDaily)]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            
            var MyConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var AwaitFileNotReadyRetryTimer = MyConfig.GetValue<int>("MyConfig:AwaitFileNotReadyRetryTimer");
            var TimerTriggerDaily = MyConfig.GetValue<string>("MyConfig:TimerTriggerDaily");
```

Here is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "MyConfig": {
    "TimerTriggerDaily": "0 0 0 * * *",
    "AwaitFileNotReadyRetryTimer": 10000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My settings are initialized after the TimerTrigger is called. Added my paramter under Values in the settings.json file.  And it worked!